# Trying to repeat a function on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game for two players. There is a little window on the side next to the game with lights beside `P1` and `P2`. The `P1light` starts green, and `P2light` starts red. When you click any square it flips the colors so `P1light` is red and `P2Light` is green. And it should then switch again after you click another square but it doesn't. Here is my code for the function. I've tried while loops, and for loops and it doesn't seem to work.

```
var x; // just so I can refer to the function as true or false

function switcher(){
    if (p1Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e"){
        p2Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e";
        p1Light.style.backgroundColor = "#ce2e1c";
        x = true;
    }else {
        x = false;
    };
};

function switcher2(){
    if (p2Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e"){
        p2Light.style.backgroundColor = "#ce2e1c";
        p1Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e";
        x = false;
    } else {
        x = true;
    };
};
```

Comment: You should use double equals for conditionals `==`

Comment: `==` doesn't work, and neither does `===`

Comment: Ideally you should `===` triple equals actually, since `==` will do type casting which in some scenarios could give unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't only fix the problem. I optimize it so that you can use only one function `switcher()` to switch colors for each player's turn. I also understand that your x is the current player's turn. If I am mistaken then feel free to adjust or notify me to fix it.

```js
const styleGreen = "#5fd81e"
const styleRed = "#ce2e1c"
let playerTurn = 1  // Starts from player 1

switcher = () => {
  // Player 1's turn
  if (playerTurn % 2 === 1) {
    p1Light.style.backgroundColor = styleGreen
    p2Light.style.backgroundColor = styleRed
  }
  // Player 2's turn
  else {
    p2Light.style.backgroundColor = styleGreen
    p1Light.style.backgroundColor = styleRed
  }
  playerTurn++
}
```

```html
<div id="p1Light">1</div>
<div id="p2Light">2</div>
<button onclick="switcher()">Switch Turn</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`style.backgroundColor` can only get color if you difined property directly .Also it will return `rgb` color code ! So need to use getComputedStyle and to compare color you need to create extra element for temporarily setting compare color .

```
var x; // just so I can refer to the function as true or false

function tempColor(color) {
  var ele = document.createElment("span");
  ele.setAttribute("id","temp_color");
  ele.style.display = "none";
  ele.style.color = color;
  document.body.appendChild(ele);
  return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(temp_color).color;
}

function switcher(){
    var p1Color = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(p1Light).backgroundColor;
    var compareColor = tempColor("#5fd81e");
    if (p1Color == compareColor){
        p2Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e";
        p1Light.style.backgroundColor = "#ce2e1c";
        x = true;
    }else {
        x = false;
    };
    temp_color.remove(); //remove temp element 
};

function switcher2(){
    var p2Color = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(p2Light).backgroundColor;
    var compareColor = tempColor("#5fd81e");
    if (p2Color == compareColor){
        p2Light.style.backgroundColor = "#ce2e1c";
        p1Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e";
        x = false;
    } else {
        x = true;
    };
    temp_color.remove(); //remove temp element 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accidentally assigning  `p1Light.style.backgroundColor` and `p2Light.style.backgroundColor` in your `if` conditions. This will give unexpected results (the statement will always be `true`).

Typo in `switcher()`:

```
if(p1Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e")
```

should be:

```
if(p1Light.style.backgroundColor === "#5fd81e")
```

Typo in `switcher2()`:

```
if (p2Light.style.backgroundColor = "#5fd81e"){
```

should be:

```
if (p2Light.style.backgroundColor === "#5fd81e"){
```

Hope this helps,